# Automate the pcomm login from Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, automation, mainframe

I am trying to automate my PCOMM login process. When I execute the below piece of code, I am getting an error.

```
Dim Num as Long

Set autECLConnList= 
CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLConnList")

autECLConnList.Refresh
```

The error I got is "ActiveX component can't create object." in line 2. I even checked whether the dll was missing, but it looks fine.

Comment: Any suggestions please

Comment: You'll probably get more help if you post this as a Windows problem, since this has nothing to do with a mainframe. But to help, these issues are usually complicated to resolve...I've always tackled them by writing a few lines of code to simulate what you thing Excel is doing, and then to run that under the Microsoft debugger until I pinpoint what the problem is. On the other hand, you're paying IBM for support with PCOMM, so I'd certainly be asking them for help rather than pursuing this one on my own.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, it appears you need to create the object before initializing it:

```
Dim autECLConnList as Object
```

See here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQ5Y_13.0.0/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/books/html/host_access08.htm

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Dim autECLConnList as Object

Dim Num as Long

Set autECLConnList = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLConnList")
autECLConnList.Refresh

Num = autECLConnList.Count
```

Num is the number of connections present in the autECLConnList collection for the last call to the Refresh method and The Count property is a Long data type and is read-only.